# Show that $y = \frac{2x}{x^2 +1}$ lies between $-1$ and $1$ inclusive.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, inequality, absolute-value

Prove, using an algebraic method,that $y=\frac{2x}{x^2 +1}$ lies between $-1$ and $1$ inclusive. Hence, determine the minimum and maximum points $y=\frac{2x}{x^2 +1}$ .

What I tried:

Firstly, I thought of using partial fractions but since $x^2 +1 =(x-i)(x+i)$, I don't think it is possible to show using partial fractions.

Secondly, decided to use differentiation

$y=\frac{2x}{x^2 +1}$

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {-2(x+1)(x-1)}{(x^2 +1)^2 }$

For stationary points:

$\frac {dy}{dx} = 0$

$\frac {-2(x+1)(x-1)}{(x^2 +1)^2 } = 0$

$x=-1$ or $x=1$

When $x=-1,y=-1$

When $x=1,y=1$

Therefore, this implies that $y=\frac{2x}{x^2 +1}$ lies between $-1$ and $1$ inclusive.

^I wonder if this is the correct method or did I leave out something?

The third way was using discriminant

Assume that $y=\frac{2x}{x^2 +1}$ intersects with $y=-1$ and $y=1$

For $\frac{2x}{x^2 +1} = 1$,

$x^2 -2x+1 = 0$

Discriminant = $ (-2)^2  -4(1)(1) = 0 $

For $\frac{2x}{x^2 +1} = -1$,

$x^2 +2x+1 = 0$

Discriminant = $ (2)^2  -4(1)(1) = 0 $

So, since $y=\frac{2x}{x^2 +1}$ touches $y=-1$ and $y=1$, $y=\frac{2x}{x^2 +1}$ lies between $-1$ and $1$ inclusive.

Is the methods listed correct?Is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: An alternative (equivalent to using AM-GM inequality) is to observe that
$$1-y^2=1-\frac{(2x)^2}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{(x^2+1)^2-4x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{(x^2-1)^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\ge0.$$ No need for derivatives, but trickier.

Comment: For the second attempt you still ´need to show that f is continuous and it's limits for x to +- infinity exist and are also in the given bounds.

Comment: It may be worth saying more in your differentiation argument, as all of the statements you give are also true for the equation $y = \frac{x^2 + 1}{2 x}$, for which the claim is false.

Comment: And, this must be the umpteenth time we see a variant of this. Whoever finds a good duplicate, @-ping me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second and third approaches are workable, but they lack the part proving that the fraction otherwise is between $-1$ and $1$.

For the second you use the sign of the derivate between and beyond the stationary points, especially beyond. You then can see that for $x>1$ the function is decreasing and for $x<-1$ too (and for $-1\le x\le 1$ it's increasing.

For the discriminant you consider for a given candidate value of $y$ the equation $2x/(x^2+1) = y$ which becomes

$$yx^2 - 2x + y = 0$$

which has the discriminant $(-2)^2 - 4y^2 = 4(1-y^2)$ and the equation only have solutions if $1-y^2=(1-y)(1+y)\ge 0$ which means that the factors are both positive or both negative (but they can't be both negative). So $1-y \ge 0$ and $1+y\ge 0$ that is $-1\le y\le 1$.

Comment: What does $C$ represent? Is it $y$ ?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi Yes. I renamed it as $y$ - the point is that you need to check for which $y$s there is a solution to the equation and not only for $y=\pm 1$.

Comment: So, I set $y=-1$ and $y=1$ to find the min and max points right? Didn't know I could use discriminant in such a way.

Comment: Yes, but you don't come to that conclusion just by picking the values. If you select $y=\pm 1/2$ you also get solutions, but those are not min/max points. What's important here is that if $|y|>1$ the discriminant becomes negative and therefore there are no solutions. You see that you have solutions for **any** $y\in[-1,1]$ which makes that the range of the function (and of course $\pm 1$ being the extrema).

Comment: So, I prove the range of $y$ first , then I let $y=-1$ and y=$1$ to find the min and max points? Sorry, I'm a student taking O lvls this year so it's difficult to understand and wrap my head around some of the methods here

Comment: Yes. For the actual min and max points you also have to solve for $x$.

Answer (score 6):

We need to prove that$$\left|\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\right|\leq1$$ or
$$x^2-2|x|+1\geq0$$ or
$$\left(|x|-1\right)^2\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $|x|=1$, which gives:

$(1,1)$ is a maximum point and $(-1-1)$ is a minimum point.

Done!

Answer (score 3):

> For what values of $a$ does the equation
>   $$
> \frac{2x}{1+x^2}=a
> $$
>   admit a solution?

The equation can be rewritten
$$
ax^2-2x+a=0
$$
and its discriminant is
$$
4(1-a^2)
$$
which is $\ge0$ if and only if $-1\le a\le 1$. For $a=0$ it's not a degree $2$ equation, but of course $f(0)=0$, so also $a=0$ is a value attained by the function.

Comment: This is the second method in my answer, right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee There's a subtle point.

Comment: Oh, so what you are doing is showing that $a$ or $y$ can be only certain values.Took me a while to understand. So, to show the minimum and maximum points, I let $a=-1$ and $a=1$ respectively correct?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi Yes, $-1$ and $1$ are the minimum and maximum values. Note that for $a=\pm1$ the equation has a double root, so the points of minimum and maximum are unique.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

If calculus is not mandatory,

**Method**$\#1:$

Set $x=\tan A$

**Method**$\#2:$

$$\implies x^2y-2x+y=0$$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

**Method**$\#3:$

If $x>0,$  $$\dfrac{2x}{x^2+1}=\dfrac2{x+\dfrac1x}$$

Now using AM-GM inequality, $$\dfrac{x+\dfrac1x}2\ge\sqrt{x\cdot\dfrac1x}=?$$

If $x<0,$ set $x=-u$

Comment: Do you mind explaining methods 1 and 2 ? I'm extremely confused...

Comment: @ArcNeoepi, By $(1),$ we have $\dfrac{2x}{x^2+1}=\sin2A$  right? What is your confusion with $(2)?$ Just proceed from where I have left

Comment: For $(1)$, how did you notice that ? For $(2)$, why is it $x^2 y -2x +y=0$. I get $(2)$ now, it's explained at the top by someone else.

Comment: @ArcNeoepi, See egreg's answer for $(2)$  $(1)$  reminded me of http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml

Answer (score 1):

i would write
$$-1\le \frac{2x}{x^2+1}\le 1$$ this is equivalent to
$$-x^2-1\le 2x$$ or $$(x+1)^2\geq 0$$ and $$2x\le x^2+1$$ this is equivalent to $$(x-1)^2\geq 0$$

Comment: How are the first inequalities equivalent to the second? Clearly $-x^2-1\leq 2x\leq x^2+1$, but how have you eliminated the RHS?

Comment: you will have $$-x^2-1\le 2x$$ and $$2x\le x^2+1$$

Comment: $(x-1)^2\geq 0$ this part implies that $x$ cannot be $1$ am I correct ? while $(x+1)^2\geq 0$ implies $x$ also cannot be $-1$. So what does it mean?I'm a bit lost

Comment: if $$(x-1)^2\geq 0$$ this implies also that $x$ can be $1$ and $$(x+1)^2$$ implies also that $x$ can be $-1$

Comment: Wait, so , $x$ can be all real numbers, so this is for proving that $y$ is continuous but does this show that $y$ lie between $-1$ and $1$ ? Or is it the part I'm missing in my workings?

Answer (score 1):

use AM-GM:

If $x>0$ then $$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\le\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{2x}{2x}=1$$

Similarly $x<0$

$$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\ge\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{2x}{2|x|}=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Squares are non-negative so 
$$-(x+1)^2\le 0\le (x-1)^2$$
so
$$-x^2-2x-1\le 0\le x^2-2x+1$$
so
$$-x^2-1\le {2x}\le x^2+1$$
so
$$-1\le \frac{2x}{x^2+1}\le 1$$
since this is division by $x^2+1>0$

Answer (score 1):

All this is usually summarized in a good old variation table.

$$f(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\quad,\quad f'(x)=\frac{-2(x-1)(x+1)}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

$\begin{array}{|l|ccccccc|}\hline
x & -\infty& & -1  && 1 && +\infty\\
\hline
f'&& - & 0 & + & 0 & -\\ 
\hline
f&0&\searrow&-1&\nearrow&+1&\searrow&0\\
\hline
\end{array}$

Adding that $x^2+1$ does not annulate, thus $f$ is continuous and so range is given by the closed interval made of miminum and maximum values in the table since they are reached : $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\frac{2x}{x^2+1}=\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+1}-1$$
it suffices to show that $\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+1}\le2$, as this expression is clearly positive. This is obvious, since
$$\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+1}-2=-\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2+1}\le 0$$