# Diagram of $1+ 2\cdot [\frac{x}{1+x^2}]$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to draw the diagram of this function:
$y=f(x)= 1+ 2\cdot[\frac{x}{1+x^2}]$

in which $[\frac{x}{1+x^2}]$ is the whole part of $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$
Can someone help me to understand what to do in this case?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361415/show-that-y-frac2xx2-1-lies-between-1-and-1-inclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=0$
$$\frac x{1+x^2}=0$$
If $0< x\le 1$
$$0<\frac x{1+x^2}<\frac x1\le1$$
If $x>1$
$$0<\frac x{1+x^2}<\frac x{x^2}=\frac1x<1$$
If $-1\le x<0$
$$0>\frac x{1+x^2}>\frac1x>-1$$
If $x<-1$
$$0>\frac x{1+x^2}>\frac x{x^2}=\frac1x>-1$$

Then,
$$\left\lfloor\frac x{1+x^2}\right\rfloor=\begin{cases}0\text{ if }x\ge 0\\-1\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $g(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$ takes values between $\pm\frac12$. It has the same sign as $x$, so $\lfloor g(x)\rfloor$ is $0$ for $x\geq 0 $ and $-1$ for $x<0$.

So your function $f(x)$ is $1$ for $x\geq 0$ and $-1$ for $x<0$.