# Prove that domain is consist of only two points.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

Prove that f(x)=sin$^{-1}$$\frac{1+x^{2}}{2x}$ - $\frac{\Pi}{2}sec(x-1)$
contains only twpo points in domain namely{-1,1}.

I tried but i could not do this.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361415/show-that-y-frac2xx2-1-lies-between-1-and-1-inclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contains only twpo points in domai ,because $$\frac{1+x^2}{2x}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x^2}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac1x) \\\text {we know } |x+\frac 1x|\geq 2 \\\to |\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac1x)|\geq \frac{2}{2}=1 \\\frac{1+x^2}{2x} \in (-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty)$$ and $$D_{\sin ^{-1} u}=[-1,1]$$now $$[-1,1] \cap \left(  (-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty)\right)=\{1,-1\}$$

Comment: Can you just suggest me a book for this kind of questions.?

Comment: @KislayTripathi : this is special question ,I don't think there is a book with this kind only . you can use famous inequality to find domain and range of some function